# Laravel Cashier Stripe_Event api key defaults to NULL?

Tags: php, laravel, webhooks

I'm using Stripe and its webhooks. I've got my own controller that extends Cashier's own Webhook controller. I noticed that Cashier's webhook controller has a method called `handleWebhook` that checks if an event exists on Stripe:

```
public function handleWebhook()
{
    $payload = $this->getJsonPayload();

    if ( ! $this->eventExistsOnStripe($payload['id']))
    {
        return;
    }
    // More code...
}

protected function eventExistsOnStripe($id)
{
    try
    {
        return ! is_null(Stripe_Event::retrieve($id));
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now the Stripe_Event class has the retrieve function with the apiKey as one of its parameters defaulting to NULL:

```
  public static function retrieve($id, $apiKey=null)
  {
    $class = get_class();
    return self::_scopedRetrieve($class, $id, $apiKey);
  }
```

The NULL apiKey is preventing me from executing my code when I receive a webhook from Stripe. Is this NULL value intentional and i'm doing something wrong? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Stripe API key manually. I have also extended Cashier's webhook controller and added this constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
    Stripe::setApiKey(Config::get('services.stripe.secret'));
    Stripe::setApiVersion("2015-10-16"); // use your Stripe API version
}
```

Don't forget the `use Config, Stripe` statements at the top of your class.